# Parse data and get a variable from a text

Tags: python

I have a text in a variable, like this for example:

```
some text bla bla bla bla bla \n - IP sources {0:192.168.1.1, 1:192.168.1.2, 2:192.168.1.3}\n some text bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
```

I wanna parse that data and get at the end variables that contain those IP adresse, so the output should look like that:

```
varibale1 = 192.168.1.1
variable2 = 192.168.1.2
variable3 = 192.168.1.3
```

Could you help me with that please ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: did you try using regex?

Comment: Honestly I am new using python (I used to programme with C++), so I don't know that predefined functions. I will search about regex and see if it solves my problem. Thank you @deadshot

Comment: yep you should look at regular expressions with python, it really helps a lot it actually saved my life a lot of times.

Comment: Does anybody think the same could be done with `argparse` and passing the text as command line argument when launching the script?

Comment: r"\d:(?P<ip>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})"